# In Excel, Sum hierarchical data based on existence of subdata

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, visual-basic

I have a set of rows like this that display some hierarchical data.

```
      A  |    B    | C | D | E | F 

1   Task |         | 1 |   | 2 |  
2   Task |         | 1 |   | 2 |  
3   Task |         |   |   | 8 |  
4        | Subtask |   | 2 |   | 4  
5        | Subtask |   | 2 |   | 4  
6   Task |         | 1 |   | 2 |   
7   Task |         | 1 |   | 2 |
```

Columns A and B are tasks and subtasks, columns C and D are inputs corresponding to each task/subtask.  Columns E and F are transformations columns C & D (here they're simply doubled).

Notice that C3 is empty, because the task is not given a value directly; rather it is the sum of the subtasks.  Correspondingly, E3 is =SUM(F4:F5).

Currently I do this manually.  I would like a function that would do something like the following pseudocode:

```
IF(
  NOT(C3=""),
  C3,
  SUM_UNTIL(E:E,NOT(""),F:F)
)
```

So the cell E3 would:

- use the value in C3 if C3 is not blank.
- If C3 is blank, SUM() the cells in F4:F for any number of contiguous blank cells in C.

I am pretty good to very good in excel.  Also, I am a programmer, but I don't know VB at all (linux guy), so I'd be happy with a VB solution.  I am fluent in JavaScript so that would work too if there's some sort of javascript plugin for excel).

**I'm using the latest version of Excel (maybe 2016?  The one in the latest business edition of office).**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the most efficient formula, but this works

```
=IF(AND(ISBLANK(B3); ISBLANK(C3));
    SUM(INDIRECT("F"&ROW()+1&":
                  F"&MATCH(TRUE; INDEX($B4:$B$16=""; 0); 0)+ROW()-1));
    C3*2)
```

### Explanation

`AND(ISBLANK(B3); ISBLANK(C3));` detects when to start sum formula. It requires **both** cell `B3` and `C3` to be empty (if you only use `C3`, then `C4` and `C5` will also trigger the sum formula, instead of doubling their value)

`INDIRECT( ... )` forms the range to be used in the `SUM`

`"F"&ROW()+1&":` the range start at `F` and below the current row (in this example `F4`)

`F"&MATCH(TRUE; INDEX($B4:$B$16=""; 0); 0)+ROW())` and ends at the `F` row on the next blank cell on column `B`

**Note:** please remember that the range starts and ends one row below the current row. Also note the position of absolute signs (**$**)

---

**Further explanation on `MATCH(TRUE; INDEX($B4:$B$16=""; 0); 0)+ROW()-1`**
I found the formula [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24061196/match-formula-when-first-cell-in-search-range-is-empty)

First, `INDEX($B4:$B$16=""; 0)` creates an array whether `B4 = ""` and `B5 = ""` and so on. You can see this array by putting the formula on row 1 on any column, and change `0` to `ROW()-1` and dragging the formula down.

```
FALSE
FALSE
FALSE
TRUE
and so on...
```

Then, `MATCH(TRUE; ... ; 0)` will find the first `TRUE`, that is the first ***next*** blank row *after this row* (returning the index **3**)

However, the result is the *index of the array* **3**, instead of *row number*. So we add the index with current row, 3 + 3, and *voila!* We have the row number
of the next blank row. Just add `-1` to make sure we are summing the correct range of `F4:F5`, not `F4:F6`.

Comment: Thanks!  This worked very well.  For anyone else finding it useful:  The big trick to remember is that the INDIRECT("F"&ROW()+1":F"... portion will not drag horizontally (the "F" has to be modified manually each time you change rows).